# Power Automate - Adding a DL in the approver email secttion

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval-process, power-automate

I have a leave approval workflow where the leave request mail goes to the direct Manager.
However, I want to add a DL as well so that other Managers can also receive the mail in case the direct Manager is not available.

I tried to add the email section like: @{body('Get_manager_(V2)')?['mail']}; 123@abc.com

However, the mail only goes to the direct manager and not the DL. Are DL's not allowed or am I doing anything wrong here?

I separated both emails addresses by semi colon.

Comment: Add a "Compose" action to see the output of the email addresses before sending the email

Answer (score 0):

If you use the **Start and wait for an approval** action, the flow sends the approval request only one at a time, not in parallel.

Use the **Create an approval** action so that it sends emails to all receipts all at once.

See the references here:

[Building a Modern SharePoint Solution: Part 7 – Creating a Multiple Approver Microsoft Flow.](https://prairiedeveloper.com/2018/08/creating-a-multiple-approver-microsoft-flow/)

[Create parallel approval workflows with Power Automate.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/parallel-modern-approvals)

Comment: Thank You. If I want to continue using Start and wait for an approval action, can I just add the DL? I tried doing so, but it gave me an error saying invalid user. Are DL's not supported?

Comment: @NikhilaMenon Per my test, it won't work. I suppose it's not supported.